# Dynamically assign value to dynamic Object

Tags: c#-4.0

```
dynamic contacts = new List<dynamic>();
contacts.Add(new ExpandoObject());
contacts[0].Name = "Patrick Hines" ;
contacts[0].Phone = "206-555-0144" ;
```

Want to do as below.

```
dynamic contacts = new List<dynamic>();
contacts.Add(new ExpandoObject());
contacts[0]. + "Name" = "Patrick Hines" ;
contacts[0]. + "Phone" = "206-555-0144" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
var contacts = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
contacts.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>());

contacts[0]["Name"] = "Patrick Hines";
contacts[0]["Phone"] = "206-555-0144";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access members of an `ExpandoObject` by name if you access it as an `IDictionary<string, object>`.  Make your list as a `List<IDictionary<string, object>>`, this would allow you to do things like this:

```
var contacts = new List<IDictionary<string, object>> { new ExpandoObject() };
contacts[0]["Name"] = "Patrick Hines";

var asDynamic = contacts as dynamic;
asDynamic[0].Phone = "206-555-0144";
```

Comment: Thanks so much.Done!